# Groupby data horizontally in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset on which I applied the `groupby` like this:

```
dc = d.groupby(['Kit Status','kit_type'])['transaction_no'].count()
```

The output of the above is this:

```
Kit Status  kit_type
Onsite      Crate        84
            FLC          70
            PP Box       91
Return      Crate        49
            FLC          96
            PP Box      141
Name: transaction_no, dtype: int64
```

How can I create a new dataframe from the above occupied data which is horizonal rather than vertical

Expected output:

```
Product    Allotment    Onsite    Return
Crate      133          84         49
FLC        166          70         96
PP Box     232          91         141
```

where `Allotment` is the sum of `onsite` and `Return`

Comment: Do you mean from the original dataframe or the computed one?

Comment: Do you need column `transaction_no` sum per groups or count number of values per groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If use `count` is is used for count values from column `transaction_no` with exclude missing values.

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) by first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
dc = (d.groupby(['Kit Status','kit_type'])['transaction_no']
       .count()
       .rename_axis([None,'Product'])
       .unstack(0)
       .reset_index())
```

If want count all values include missing values (if exist):

```
dc = (pd.crosstab(d['kit_type'], d['Kit Status'])
        .rename_axis(index='Product', columns=None)
        .reset_index())
```

Last for new sum column in first position of columns use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
dc.insert(0, 'Allotment', dc.sum(axis=1))
print (dc)
```

Comment: How do I change the name of `Kit status Kit type` to `Product` ? I tried `dc.rename(columns={ dc.columns[0]: "Product" }, inplace = True)` but it renamed `Onsite`

Comment: @RahulSharma - Can you check edited answer?

Comment: @DaniMesejo - Do you think `count` exclude NaNs ?

Comment: @jezrael I think the OP wants the sum, but better to ask him directly

Comment: @DaniMesejo - Understand, you think insert column `Allotment`

Answer (score 0):

From a Series (similar to the one in question), like this:

```
Kit Status  kit_type
Onsite      Crate        84
            FLC          70
            PP Box       91
Return      Crate        49
            FLC          96
            PP Box      141
Name: transaction_no, dtype: int64
```

You could use [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
dc = df.to_frame().reset_index()

res = pd.crosstab(dc['kit_type'], dc['Kit Status'], dc['transaction_no'], aggfunc='sum', margins=True,
                  margins_name='Allotment').drop('Allotment')

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
Kit Status  Onsite  Return  Allotment
kit_type                             
Crate           84      49        133
FLC             70      96        166
PP Box          91     141        232
```